# HDF5: Compound Data Type with Variable Length String to Packet Table

Tags: c, hdf5

I've successfully exported a fixed length compound data type to a packet table using the following code:

```
typedef struct moddata_t {
    char cLog[4096];
} moddata_t;
//  
//  Attempt to open the revision history packet table
hid_t hidPTableID = H5PTopen(hidID, "Revision History");
//
//  Create copy of native character type
hid_t hidCharLen4096TypeID = H5Tcopy(H5T_C_S1);
//
//  Set size of character type
H5Tset_size(hidCharLen4096TypeID, 4096);
//
//  Create memory data type for compound data
hid_t hidModDataTypeID = H5Tcreate(H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof(moddata_t));
H5Tinsert(hidModDataTypeID, "log", HOFFSET(moddata_t, cLog), hidCharLen4096TypeID);
//
//  Create fixed length packet table
hidPTableID = H5PTcreate(hidID, "Revision History", hidModDataTypeID, 1, H5P_DEFAULT);
//
//  Free resources
H5Tclose(hidModDataTypeID);
H5Tclose(hidCharLen4096TypeID);
//
//  Fill data type
//    NOTE:  get() function returns a string with miscellaneous info to be exported to packet table
moddata_t modDat;
strcpy(modDat.cLog, get().c_str());
//
//  Append data to packet table
herr_t herrErr = H5PTappend(hidPTableID, 1, &modDat);
//
//  Close packet table
H5PTclose(hidPTableID);
```

However, if I change to use a variable length string, I get a segfault somewhere inside HDF5 when H5PTappend is called.  Unfortunately, there aren't very many examples using a packet table.  Here is the modified code that fails:

```
typedef struct moddata_t {
    hvl_t cLogHandle;
} moddata_t;
//  
//  Attempt to open the revision history packet table
hid_t hidPTableID = H5PTopen(hidID, "Revision History");
//
//  Create copy of native character type
hid_t hidCharLenVarTypeID = H5Tcopy(H5T_C_S1);
//
//  Set size of character type
H5Tset_size(hidCharLenVarTypeID, H5T_VARIABLE);
//
//  Create memory data type for compound data
hid_t hidModDataTypeID = H5Tcreate(H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof(moddata_t));
H5Tinsert(hidModDataTypeID, "log", HOFFSET(moddata_t, cLogHandle), hidCharLenVarTypeID);
//
//  Create fixed length packet table
hidPTableID = H5PTcreate(hidID, "Revision History", hidModDataTypeID, 1, H5P_DEFAULT);
//
//  Free resources
H5Tclose(hidModDataTypeID);
H5Tclose(hidCharLen4096TypeID);
//
//  Fill data type
//    NOTE:  get() function returns a string with miscellaneous info to be exported to packet table
moddata_t modDat;
modDat.cLogHandle.len = get().length() + 1;   // Added one for \0 character;
modDat.cLogHandle.p = new char [get().length()+1];
strcpy((char *) modDat.cLogHandle.p, get().c_str());
//
//  Append data to packet table
herr_t herrErr = H5PTappend(hidPTableID, 1, &modDat);
//
//  Close packet table
H5PTclose(hidPTableID);
```

Piecing together what others have done to declare compound datatypes with variable length elements, I think I'm creating the datatype correctly.  However, there isn't much defining the **hvl_t** structure so I'm not sure that I'm correctly defining the **len** and **p** variables and this is why it is segfaulting.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off if you use a higher-level API such as [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as it deals with HDF5 compound datasets/attributes in a very simple and intuitive way (from a developer point-of-view). Take a look at HDFql [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) where you can get many examples on how to create, read and write compound datasets/attributes in `C` (besides other languages such as `C++`, `Java`, `Python`, `C#`, `R` and `Fortran`).

Comment: Unfortunately, I would like to stick with only HDF5 library dependencies.  It was already a heavy lift to get my customers to use HDF5 let alone yet another library that isn't available as a 'yum' install option (at least for CEntOS/RedHat 7.x)...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

If I remove:

```
 //
 //  Create copy of native character type
 hid_t hidCharLenVarTypeID = H5Tcopy(H5T_C_S1);
 //
 //  Set size of character type
 H5Tset_size(hidCharLenVarTypeID, H5T_VARIABLE);
```

and replace with:

```
 hid_t hidCharLenVarTypeID = H5Tvlen_create(H5T_C_S1);
```

Then it seems to work.  However, coming from this https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5T.html#CreateVLString, it says:

> **Creating variable-length string datatypes**
>
> As the term implies, variable-length strings are strings of varying lengths; they can be arbitrarily long, anywhere from 1 character to thousands of characters.
>
> HDF5 provides the ability to create a variable-length string datatype. Like all string datatypes, this type is based on the atomic string datatype: H5T_C_S1 in C or H5T_FORTRAN_S1 in Fortran. While these datatypes default to one character in size, they can be resized to specific fixed lengths or to variable length.
>
> Variable-length strings will transparently accommodate ASCII strings or UTF-8 strings. This characteristic is set with H5Tset_cset in the process of creating the datatype.
>
> The following HDF5 calls create a C-style variable-length string datatype, vls_type_c_id:

```
vls_type_c_id = H5Tcopy(H5T_C_S1)  
status = H5Tset_size(vls_type_c_id, H5T_VARIABLE)
```

> In a C environment, variable-length strings will always be NULL-terminated, so the buffer to hold such a string must be one byte larger than the string itself to accommodate the NULL terminator.

So there seems to be some confusion how to declare a variable length string.

John